# Mini Programming Language in Haskell

Tags: haskell, semantics

I'm playing around with Haskell and thought I'd try to create a simple programming language with it.  Ignoring the concrete syntax for now; I am concentrating on the abstract syntax and the semantics.

The language currently should consist of integers, integer addition, variable names, and variable binding blocks.

If a variable is used that doesn't exist in the scope it is used, an error is raised.

The following is my current progress:

```
module ProgLang where
import Data.Map as Map

--  Classes
class Runnable d where
  run :: (Runnable a) => d -> Map String a -> Either [String] Integer

--  Data
data Name = Name String
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Add a b = Add a b
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Block a = Block (Map String a) a
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

--  Instances
--  Integers resolve to Right Integer
instance Runnable Integer where
  run v _ = Right v

--  For Names
--    look up their expression in the scope, then evaluate
--    if name is out of scope, raise an error
instance Runnable Name where
  run (Name n) s = which (Map.lookup n s) where
    which Nothing = Left ["Variable not in scope: " ++ n]
    which (Just v) = run v s

--  For Addition
--    Run a, Run b, Add their results
--    Raise appropriate errors where necessary
instance (Runnable a, Show a, Runnable b, Show b) => Runnable (Add a b) where
  run (Add a b) s = geta (run a s) where
    geta (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In lhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
    geta (Right a') = getb a' (run b s)
    getb _ (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In rhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
    getb a' (Right b') = Right (a' + b')

--  For Blocks
--    Run the block's expression under a new scope
--      (merging the current with the block's scope definition)
instance Runnable a => Runnable (Block a) where
  run (Block s' e) s = result $ run e (Map.union s' s) where
    result (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In block: " ++ show (Block s' e)])
    result (Right v) = Right v
```

I am using `(Runnable a) => Either [String] a` as the outcome of `run`.  `Left` for errors and `Right` for a valid result.

The following are example expressions and their expected outcome:

```
--  run 5 Map.empty
--  => Right 5

--  run (Name "a") Map.empty
--  => Left ["Variable not in scope: a"]

--  run (Name "a") (fromList [("a", 6)])
--  => Right 6

--  run (Add 6 3) Map.empty
--  => Right 9

--  run (Add (Name "a") 7) (fromList [("a", 10)])
--  => Right 17

--  run (Block (fromList [("a", 10)]) (Name "a")) Map.empty
--  => Right 10
```

I am getting the following error from GHCI (version 7.4.1):

```
progLang.hs:45:53:
    Could not deduce (a1 ~ a)
    from the context (Runnable a)
      bound by the instance declaration at progLang.hs:44:10-41
    or from (Runnable a1)
      bound by the type signature for
                 run :: Runnable a1 =>
                        Block a -> Map String a1 -> Either [String] Integer
      at progLang.hs:(45,3)-(47,30)
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for
             run :: Runnable a1 =>
                    Block a -> Map String a1 -> Either [String] Integer
           at progLang.hs:45:3
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at progLang.hs:44:19
    Expected type: Map String a1
      Actual type: Map String a
    In the second argument of `union', namely `s'
    In the second argument of `run', namely `(union s' s)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This error (as far as I can tell) is due to the Block's run function.  It doesn't seem to like the call to `Map.union`.

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.  Any ideas?  Should I be attempting a completely different approach to this project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the way that `run` is declared.

```
run :: (Runnable a) => d -> Map String a -> Either [String] Integer
```

What you probably intended is that the second argument is a `Map` from `String` to *any* runnables, mingled together in the same map. But what this *actually* means is that the second argument is a `Map` from `String` to *one particular* kind of runnable (it's just not known which it is).

Rather than using a typeclass and disparate types, try using a single type instead.

```
module ProgLang where
import Data.Map as Map

data Runnable
  = Name String
  | Add Runnable Runnable
  | Block (Map String Runnable) Runnable
  | I Integer
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

run :: Runnable -> Map String Runnable -> Either [String] Integer
--  Instances
--  Integers resolve to Right Integer
run (I v) _ = Right v
--  For Names
--    look up their expression in the scope, then evaluate
--    if name is out of scope, raise an error
run (Name n) s = which (Map.lookup n s) where
  which Nothing = Left ["Variable not in scope: " ++ n]
  which (Just v) = run v s
--  For Addition
--    Run a, Run b, Add their results
--    Raise appropriate errors where necessary
run (Add a b) s = geta (run a s) where
  geta (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In lhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
  geta (Right a') = getb a' (run b s)
  getb _ (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In rhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
  getb a' (Right b') = Right (a' + b')
--  For Blocks
--    Run the block's expression under a new scope
--      (merging the current with the block's scope definition)
run (Block s' e) s = result $ run e (Map.union s' s) where
  result (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In block: " ++ show (Block s' e)])
  result (Right v) = Right v
```

The only change I made to this code was the type declarations and reorganization of the `run` function.

If you add a dummy `Num` instance with `fromInteger = I` then you can also use integer literals as `Runnable`s. Here's a test run with the test cases you supplied, looks like all the expected outputs match: http://ideone.com/9UbC5.

Answer (score 2):

You miss `Show a` constraint. If you put your `run` outside of instance declaration (I renamed it to `xrun`) like this

```
xrun (Block s' e) s = result $ run e (Map.union s' s) where
    result (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In block: " ++ show (Block s' e)])
    result (Right v) = Right v
```

`ghci` says that

```
*ProgLang> :t xrun
xrun
  :: (Show a, Runnable a) =>
     Block a -> Map String a -> Either [[Char]] Integer
```

But it's not enough to fix the constraint. Put two types side by side (the one in class declaration and actual type of `xrun`:

```
 run ::         (Runnable a) => d       -> Map String a -> Either [String] Integer
xrun :: (Show a, Runnable a) => Block a -> Map String a -> Either [String] Integer
```

The difference is that your class promises that given `d` your `run` should work for any runnable `a`. But `xrun` doesn't fullfill this requirement: if `d` is `Block Int`, it cannot work with arbitrary `a`, but only with `a :: Int`.

So as other commenters said you probably need to change your class declaration. One approach could be existential types:

```
data AnyRunnable = forall a . (Runnable a) => AnyRunnable a 

class Runnable d where
    run :: d -> Map String AnyRunnable -> Either [String] Integer
```

This is a different contract: now the `Map` can contain runnables of different types. Here is the full solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module ProgLang where
import Data.Map as Map

data AnyRunnable = forall a . (Runnable a) => AnyRunnable a 

instance Show AnyRunnable where
    show (AnyRunnable a) = show a

instance Runnable AnyRunnable where
    run (AnyRunnable a) = run a

--  Classes
class Show d => Runnable d where
   run :: d -> Map String AnyRunnable -> Either [String] Integer

--  Data
data Name = Name String
  deriving (Show)

data Add a b = Add a b
  deriving (Show)

data Block a = Block (Map String AnyRunnable) a
  deriving (Show)

--  Instances
--  Integers resolve to Right Integer
instance Runnable Integer where
  run v _ = Right v


--  For Names
--    look up their expression in the scope, then evaluate
--    if name is out of scope, raise an error
instance Runnable Name where
  run (Name n) s = which (Map.lookup n s) where
    which Nothing = Left ["Variable not in scope: " ++ n]
    which (Just v) = run v s

--  For Addition
--    Run a, Run b, Add their results
--    Raise appropriate errors where necessary
instance (Runnable a, Show a, Runnable b, Show b) => Runnable (Add a b) where
  run (Add a b) s = geta (run a s) where
    geta (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In lhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
    geta (Right a') = getb a' (run b s)
    getb _ (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In rhs of expression: " ++ show (Add a b)])
    getb a' (Right b') = Right (a' + b')

--  For Blocks
--    Run the block's expression under a new scope
--      (merging the current with the block's scope definition)
instance Runnable a => Runnable (Block a) where
  run (Block s' e) s = result $ run e (Map.union s' s) where
    result (Left es) = Left (es ++ ["In block: " ++ show (Block s' e)])
    result (Right v) = Right v
```

Test like this:

```
run (Block (fromList [("a", AnyRunnable 10)]) (Name "a")) Map.empty
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the signature of `run`.

```
class Runnable d where
  run :: Runnable a => d -> Map String a -> Either [String] Integer
```

Particularly, `run` has two *different* type variables `a` and `d`; the only constraint on them is that they are both in `Runnable`. This means the function has to work for *any* pair of runnable types `a` and `d`. However, for blocks, this does not make sense--you cannot run a `Block a` with anything but a `Map String a` since you do your union operation. Thus your implementation for `run` is not as general as the type signature wants it to be--your implementation implies that the `a` in `Block a` is the same as the *different* variable `a1` in `Map String a1`, but the type of `run` leaves you no way to enforce this.

You can actually fix this with multi-parameter typeclasses and make the fact that the `a` in `Block a` has to be the same as the type of the `Map` explicit. In fact, this may be a good learning exercise to understand multi-parameter typeclasses (which are exactly what they sound like but also really cool). However, the best solution would be to rewrite your code not to use typeclasses here at all--use an algebraic dtta type to represent your abstract syntax instead. This is the most common and most convenient way to represent abstract syntaxes in Haskell.